Finding the Supremum of a Polynomial with Bounded Values on a Discrete Sequence — Possibly Related to Approximation Theory?
I have encountered a question that I believe may be related to approximation theory, but I'm unsure about the specifics of this relationship. Could anyone share insights on it?
Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $k$. Given constants $b, c$ and $t$, let $n > k + 1 \in \mathbb{Z}$. Assume that there exists a sequence of points $0 < x_1 < x_2 <... < x_n < b$ such that: $|x_{i+1} - x_i| > t$, for $i = 1,..., n-1$.
Additionally, we have $|P(x_i)| < c$  for $i = 1,..., n$.
Now, can I provide an upper bound for $\max_{x\in[x_1, x_n]} |P(x)|$?
Thank you in advance for your help!
